# Trying to change color for input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've started coding and created a function so the background color changes to your preference but id like it to change the button color too so it looks better but nothing seems to work

This is all I've done so far

```js
function changeBG() {
  var selectedBGColor = document.getElementById("bgchoice").value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedBGColor;
}
```

```html
<section class="no-padding-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Change Colour</h5>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select id="bgchoice" name="colour" class="form-control">
            <option value="red">preset</option>
            <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="blue">Sea</option>
            <option value="violet">Violet</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="changecolour" value="Change Colour" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeBG()" id="bgchoice">
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If that's all you've done so far, of course "nothing seems to work" -- you've tried nothing. Try getting a reference to the button (note that ids must be unique to the document, and you have the same id on both the `select` and the `button`) and see where you can get to from there.

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique , so change it and you can change color for button too:

```js
function changeBG() {
  let selectedBGColor = document.querySelector("#bgchoice").value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedBGColor; 
  document.querySelector("#btnbgchoice").style.backgroundColor = selectedBGColor
}
```

```html
<section class="no-padding-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Change Colour</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="bgchoice" name="colour" class="form-control">
              <option value="red">preset</option>
              <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
              <option value="green">Green</option>
              <option value="pink">Pink</option>
              <option value="blue">Sea</option>
              <option value="violet">Violet</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="changecolour" value="Change Colour" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeBG()" id="btnbgchoice">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution:
Pass the Object of element in function and set the value on click of button itself.

```js
function changeBG(ele) {
  ele.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("bgchoice").value;
}
```

```html
<section class="no-padding-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Change Colour</h5>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select id="bgchoice" name="colour" class="form-control">
            <option value="red">preset</option>
            <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="blue">Sea</option>
            <option value="violet">Violet</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="changecolour" value="Change Colour" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeBG(this)" id="bgchoice">
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you i added it to my code and it works

Answer (score 0):

Like Heretic said, double check your id naming. The button and input fields have the same `id` when ids are unique.

```
<body>
    <script>
            function changeBG() {
                var selectedBGColor = document.getElementById("bgchoice").value;
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = selectedBGColor;
                document.getElementById("bgbutton").style.backgroundColor = selectedBGColor
            }
        </script>
<div id="app">
    <section class="no-padding-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Change Colour</h5>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="bgchoice" name="colour" class="form-control">
                            <option value="red">preset</option>
                            <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
                            <option value="green">Green</option>
                            <option value="pink">Pink</option>
                            <option value="blue">Sea</option>
                            <option value="violet">Violet</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" name="changecolour" value="Change Colour" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeBG()" id="bgbutton">
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an speed alternative with jQuery:

```
$("#identifier").css("background-color", "blue");
```